# How to swap two parts of a filename

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a bunch of files name like this

```
name-id.ext
```

and I want to swap the id and name in the file so they are named

```
id-name.ext
```

This seems to be working, the only issue is that it swaps the file extention too

```
for file in *; do echo "${file#*-}-${file%-*}"; done
```

Comment: I've been trying to find all kinds of things, this is what ive come up with so far and I think should work but its not doing it,  for file in *; do echo "${file%-*}-${file#*-}"; done

Comment: Please edit your answer to add your code instead of adding a comment. That way you can format it and make it easier to read. You also don't force people trying to help you to dig through a bunch of comments and pick up the pieces of information.

Comment: your `${file%-}` etc looks approximately right. Did you get it to work for 1 file before running against all your files? Did you scan your files to be certain they don't have spaces or ctrl-chars in their names and that  you can reasonably expect your solution to work on all files? In the future, be sure to include the code you have tried **in the body of your Q** so people won't have to read thru an every growing chain of comments. Good luck!

Comment: The files do have spaces, but I added IFS="\n" so it should only be looking at the new line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved using a combination of:

- regular expression groups to detect the two parts of the file name to be swapped: 
  `'^(.*)-(.*)\.ext'`
- `sed` to swap the first part with the second part: 
  `sed 's/^\(.*\)-\(.*\)\.ext$/\2-\1\.ext/'`
- `echo` to pipe the old file name into sed: `echo $file | sed 's/^\(.*\)-\(.*\)\.ext$/\2-\1\.ext/'`
- store it in a variable: `newname=$(echo $file | sed 's/^\(.*\)-\(.*\)\.ext$/\2-\1\.ext/')`
- `mv` can use the chunk from the previous point as the new name: `mv $file $newname`
- The whole thing can be wrapped in a loop to go over the files:

  `for file in *ext; do
      newname=$(echo $file | sed 's/^\(.*\)-\(.*\)\.ext$/\2-\1\.ext/');
      mv $file $newname;
  done;`